# Offline Web Search

Tags: html, search, web, offline

I have a web application that I want to run offline, in an IPad. All is fine, but I would like a search facility, to search through the various pages on content.

There are plenty of on line search capabilities, especially using Ajax, but I want something that runs offline.

I have seen various people discuss snippets of code that show how searching might work, but I need something that is packages up as follows.

1. A small search text field.
2. When used, a list located pages is listed, each as a link
3. You can click on each link to take you to the page concerned.

Even an un-finished product would give me a better starting point than where I'm at right now.

Thanks in advance,
Greg Ambrose

Comment: I have used this one and worked fine for an offline application, at least for my purpose.

http://dentedreality.com.au/projects/jssearch/

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your needs correctly, you need a search function that, rather than searching your database, would search an already compiled index. If the index was compiled while online, it would still be available offline.

[Search Maker Pro](http://www.searchmakerpro.com/) has [offline search functionality](http://www.searchmakerpro.com/kb01.html) and meets your requirements--see [this demo](http://www.searchmakerpro.com/examples.html). There's also [Zoom Search Engine](http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/index.html), an alternative that looks to be good as well. Both of these require, I believe, that you do the indexing on a Windows machine and they are not free, but the best options I've seen unless you want to create the index yourself.

[Fullproof](http://reyesr.github.io/fullproof/), a Javascript-based solution, may be of assistance but it involves creating the index yourself. For further discussion on offline search, you can also see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357173/full-text-search-for-static-html-files-on-cd-rom-via-javascript).

Comment: Tim, thanks for your suggestions and I'm sorry to take so long to get back to you. This is a part time project and I've been busy elsewhere.I'll have a look at your suggestions over the holiday and get back to you.